# RecyclerView doesn't properly wrap its content when it has a max height of WRAP_CONSTRAINT

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to have a RecylerView with a varying item count wrap its height to its items, but to never have it exceed its constraints. I believe I've set this up properly. Here's a simple XML for such a layout:

```xml
<!-- container.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:background="@colors/blue">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomGreenView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@colors/green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@colors/red"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomGreenView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/test_list_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```xml
<!-- test_list_item.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@colors/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="List item here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that the container is blue, the RecyclerView is red and the bottom view that should not be exceeded is green. And since the list items are white, there is no spacing between the items and the RecyclerView should wrap around the list items, the red background of the RecyclerView should never be seen. However, you can clearly see here that the RecyclerView is in fact seen and is much taller than it should be:

[image: The problem, where the RecyclerView (whose background is red) is larger than it needs to be.]

What I'm trying to achieve is this, where the RecyclerView properly wraps its content:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve, where the RecyclerView properly wraps its content.]

Interestingly, this does actually work as expected if I have the TextView's width `wrap_content` and remove its end-to-end constraint (the latter only so that it's not being centered horizontally). However, in my actual app I need these constraints as I also have content on the right side that I don't want to potentially overlap with long texts.

To me, this feels like an issue in either ConstraintLayout or RecyclerView (or both in tandem), so I've also filed an [issue in the bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128646026). But if it is not, then I'd be happy to hear what you all have to say

Comment: A strange result. I find that if you place a `View` before or after the `TextView` with `0dp` width constrained to the top and bottom only, the layout will also work. If you take that same `View` and constrain it to the parent start and end, it will fail as you say.  This might be a work-around for you.

Comment: Oh, interesting find, @Cheticamp! Yeah, that might totally be the workaround I was looking for just to make my production code work with the current problem. Thanks! :-)

Comment: *Small update:* the issue has been picked up by a Googler. Hopefully, it'll be addressed in a later release of either `RecyclerView` or `ConstraintLayout` (or both, I don't really know where the issue lies). :-)

Comment: Update from the issue over at issuetracker.google.com: It seems like the bug was introduced in constraintlayout-1.1.0-beta2 together with the `constrainedHeight` attribute and has persisted since then. I suspect a fix might arrive sooner rather than later. Until then, the workaround above does the trick. :-)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128646026#comment11